# Drupal drag-able blocks issue

Tags: jquery, drupal, sorting, content-management-system, draggable

Druapl offers great functionality whereby blocks can be dragged up and down to reorder as shown below.
[alt text http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/with.png](http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/with.png)

However, on a couple of projects I've been working on they have disappeared during development )as shown below) but I have no idea why! It must be something that I am doing wrong but for the life of me I can't work out why.
[alt text http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/without.png](http://citywest.bangtest.co.uk/without.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the Google CDN jQuery link and normality is ensued.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Drupal has standardized on jQuery 1.3 I believe. Probably explains why this happened.

Comment: You probably already figured this out, but you don't have to remove the link. You can simply change the 1.4 to 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a temporary solution so you can just change the order *NOW*, then try this - it is not a long term solution.

Multiple jQuery/Drupal combinations present this bug (I have it on a D6 install using jQuery v1.6.1).  Open a web inspector tool (eg firebug) on the blocks page and run this jQuery command, you'll get the weight drop-downs (which is what dragging affects behind the scenes).

```
$('table.tabledrag-processed tr td').show();
```

I have a site where updating the jQuery is too big a hassle to spend time/money on right now so I've got a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that I use about once every week or two:

```
javascript:(function(){
    if( $('#block-admin-display-form').length) {
        $('table.tabledrag-processed tr td').show();
    } else {
        alert("This doesn't look like a list of drupal blocks to me..");
    }
}());
```